# Is there a possible way to get rid of the grass color mapping in a resource pack?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I'm making a Gameboy themed Minecraft resource pack, and the grass has the color mapping, even though I've made only one color for the color mapping it still has this tint, is there any way to get rid of the color mapping so it doesn't make it tinted like it is?

Comment: could you post a picture so we could see what u mean?

Answer (score -1):

In the minecraft/textures folder, create a new folder called colormap and a file inside it called grass.png. This file should just be a 256×256 square of your preferred colour.

Comment: The problem is that it's a few specific colors, and having that one color tints the colors different then what that are supposed to be. If I make another one that's blank/clear will it work?